# How can I make this loader show only after form validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I need the spinner to start only after the form is validated. Both scripts work perfectly by themselves.

Validation:

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })

})()
```

Spinner:

```
function spinner() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

I've been trying to decipher these scripts in order to combine them, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if (!form.checkValidity())` calls a [native function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) which checks whether the form is valid. (*Not* valid, actually, due to the negation operator `!`.)

Inside its brace block is what happens if the form is *not* valid.

After its brace block is what happens if the form *is* valid. Call `spinner()` there.

```
form.classList.add('was-validated')
spinner()
```